# How to handle abbreviations in questions for chatbot?

Tags: chatterbot

i have a scenario where a user can ask same question to chatbot in differnt ways. For example- the question can be "what is TB?" or it can be "what are transition benefits?". Answer to both the question is same but the way of asking question is different. I am using levenshtein_distance for statement comparison in my code but that wont work in this case as that matches letters by letters amendments. How shall i compare my statements in this case? Shall i provide both questions to my traning data or is there any other smart way to do this. Please suggest.

Answer (score 2):

I got a solution for this. We can write our own preprocessing function and call it inside the chatbot instance.

```
bot = ChatBot("Norman",
          read_only=True,
          preprocessors=[
                       'chatterbot.preprocessors.TB_Correction'
                        ])
```

And inside Preprocessors.py(present under C:\Users\User_Name\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\chatterbot ), we can add a function to it like below:

```
def TB_Correction(chatbot,statement):
    '''
    Replacing TB with Transition Benefits
    '''
    import re

    if 'TB' in statement.text:
            statement.text = re.sub(r'[T][B]','Transition Benefits',statement.text)
    return statement
```